# Flex 2 not waking up from sleep in Ubuntu 14.04, brightness controls also not working

Tags: suspend, brightness

I have a Lenovo Flex 2 with AMD A6 CPU and 4 GB RAM. It came pre-installed with Windows 8.1. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it (single boot). But I am facing problems as the laptop does not wake up from sleep, I have to power off and start it. Also brightness control is not working.

How to fix these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Flex 2, but I do know that the normal brightness setting do not work. Don't worry though you can adjust it inside on CompizConfig. I believe it in the general compiz settings, if knot type it in  in the search bar.

If you don't have CompizConfig you can download it through the software center, or via terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install CompizConfig-settings-manager
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugin-extras
```

You can also use CompizConfig to do all kinds of cool desktop effects...such ass wobbly windows, and the desktop cube. Be careful you can damage your desktop beyond repair.

As far as Flex 2 goes i don't know anything about that.This should fix your brightness issues but someone else will have to help with the Flex issues.

Comment: I installed compizConfig, under accessibility there was an option of opacity, brightness and saturation. I enabled the plugin and set the key combination for brightness up and down but it did not worked. Brightness not getting down.

Comment: I't might just be ubuntu 14.04 i've been having problems with the brightness too.